# JSON to Java object in Android not working with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, google-api, gson

I am trying to convert some JSON into a java object in android, however it does not seem to work.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Person person = gson.fromJson(s, Person.class);
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome back " + person.getDisplayName(), duration);
toast.show();
```

Where Person.class is

```
com.google.api.services.plus.model.Person
```

I am getting type conversion errors such as:

```
wrong object type: Ljava/lang/Double; Ljava/lang/Integer;
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid value for field
```

But I want to reuse this model object from the API library, so is there anyway to fix this?

EDIT:

To prove this problem in a more simple form, please refer to this example.

```
com.google.api.services.plus.model.Person;

Gson g = new Gson();

    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.setDisplayName("Test");
    p1.setCircledByCount(10);

    String json = g.toJson(p1);
    Person fromJson = g.fromJson(json, Person.class);
    System.out.println(fromJson.getDisplayName());
```

Throws the same exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field com.google.api.services.plus.model.Person.circledByCount to java.lang.Double
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks

Comment: post your model class and json

Comment: Quite honestly, you shouldn't be using GSON with that class. It's not designed to be used with GSON. It has it's own built in logic for serializing itself to JSON, and the library it's part of handles deserialization to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is the class you're using isn't meant/designed to be used with Gson.

The core issue is that `Person` extends `GenericJson` which extends `GenericData` which extends `AbstractMap<String, Object>` ... and *that* is the problem.

When Gson attempts to deserialize the JSON, it's using its `MapTypeAdapterFactory` which unfortunately causes the JSON numeric type for `"circledByCount"` to be read as a `Double` in Java.

Then the complexity of this `Person` class kicks in. If you go look at the source code it actually uses annotations and overridden `put` methods to populate the field in `Person`. If you look at the stack trace you can actually see what happens:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field com.google.api.services.plus.model.Person.circledByCount to java.lang.Double
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:680)
    at com.google.api.client.util.FieldInfo.setFieldValue(FieldInfo.java:245)
    at com.google.api.client.util.FieldInfo.setValue(FieldInfo.java:206)
    at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.put(GenericData.java:103)
    at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.put(GenericData.java:47)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:188)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
```

Gson is calling `GenericData`'s `put()` method (Because, it knows this is a `Map`). That method actually populates the annotated `circledByCount` field via reflection. And ... it's the wrong type.

So, basically ... this isn't going to work with Gson. At least not without writing a custom `JsonDeserializer` but looking at the class, that's going to be rather complicated.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It seems strange to have model classes and to use a different json serializer than GSON when it is used in many other places in the client libs. I'm sure there is a valid reason for this however!

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON `String` have a `Double` value and and the `Person` object you care casting have a `Integer` value.

Please check the `Person` object on both sides. Better if you copy and paste the same `Person` object in Android app side..

Comment: They are the same model class from the Google api as listed in the post. The json is generated by a spring mvc controller returning a person object. Could the server side Jackson serializer be causing the issue?

Comment: If the JSON string return from the server is oky it cannot be an issue of Jackson serializer. Double check  your person class .. If you can provide the JSON string and Person class in both sides server and client side..

Answer (score 0):

Your person class must have the exact same fileds and name as the JSON you parse.